# Double limit $f_n(t_n) \to 0$ implies something about the limit of $f_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits

Suppose for each $n$, $f_n\colon (0,T) \to H$ is a map where $H$ is a Hilbert space. We know that
$$f_n(t) \to f(t)\quad(n \to \infty)$$ for fixed $t$ and $$f_n(t) \to 0\quad(t \to 0)$$ 
for fixed $n$ not necessarily uniformly in $n$.

Suppose also that there is a sequence $t_n$ which is decreasing and $t_n \to 0$ such that
$$f_n(t_n) \to 0\quad(n \to \infty).$$

Am I able to deduce any information about $f(t)$ near $t=0$ due to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Actually, this additional assumption follows from the previous one. For each $n \in \mathbb N$ one can choose $t$ such that $0 < t < \tfrac 1n$ and $|f_n(t)| \le \tfrac 1n$. If you denote this as $t_n$, you have $t_n \to 0$ and $f_n(t_n) \to 0$.

The functions $f_n(x) = 1 - (1-x)^n$ (i.e., rotated $x^n$) give a counterexample, as they converge pointwise to $f(x) = 1$.